# Find minimal operations such that N will become 1 with 3 operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

We are given N as a natural number and we can do these 3 operations with him.

1)Subtract  1 from N

2)If it is even, divide by 2

3)If it divides 3, then divide by 3

We stop this when N becomes 1. We need to find minimal operations such that N will become 1

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'count' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
# The function accepts INTEGER num as parameter.
#

def count(num):
    
    count = 0 
    while num != 1:
        
        if (num % 3 ==0 ):
            count += 1
            num = num / 3
        elif((num -1) % 3 == 0):
            count += 2
            num = (num - 1) / 3
        elif (num % 2 ==0):
            count += 1
            num = num / 2
        else:
            num = num - 1
            count += 1 
            
    return count
```

This is my code. From 11 test cases it passed 9 and gave 2 wrong answers. I don't know for which test cases my code gives wrong answers. Can you help to understand where is problem?

Comment: I see no problem why your code wouldn't work. Though why use `((num -1) % 3 == 0)` condition? you said there were only three conditions.

Comment: @Nitish I am checking if N doesn't divide $3$ but (N-1) divides 3 then I subtract 1 and divide by 3 which is 2 operations therefore count+=2

Comment: are you sure it is wrong answer and not timeouts?

Comment: If you don't use that condition, it gonna -1 at the end and come again in loop and divide by three again, incrementing counter twice. Hence its not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

You make an assumption that it is better to subtract 1 and divide by 3 first if you can, but that isn't always true.

Consider 16

Your solution would be 16-15-5-4-3-1 = 5 steps

Better solution:
16-8-4-2-1 = 4 steps

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient solution but:

```
def count(num):
    count1, count2 = float('inf'), float('inf')

    if num == 1:
        return 0

    if num % 3 == 0:
        count1 = 1 + count(num // 3)

    if num % 2 == 0:
        count2 = 1 + count(num // 2)

    count3 = 1 + count(num - 1)

    return min(count1, count2, count3)
```

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems usually have a small set of rules that produce the optimal answer.

Your fundamental problem, though, is that you are assuming that your rule set is optimal with *no evidence whatsoever*.  You really have no reason to believe that it will produce the right count.

Unfortunately, answers to these kinds of questions on SO sometimes provide the correct rule set, but always seem to omit any kind of proof that the rule set is optimal.

You have to do *something* that is guaranteed to work, so unless you have that kind of proof, you should fall back on an A* search or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the non-recursive breadth-first strategy.

Say there is a queue holding lists of numbers. Initially, enter a list holding just N into the queue. Then repeat the following until the queue is empty:

1. Pick the first list in the queue.
2. Repeat 3 for all three operations.
3. Select an operation. If possible, apply it to the last list number and add the result to the end of the list. If the list is a solution, store it somewhere. If not, add it to the end of the queue.

This strategy is exhaustive and finds all solutions. Since only the minimum is of interest, we introduce a limiting bound. Once a solution list is available, we do not enter lists longer than that into the queue, nor do we consider them if they are in the queue already.